# Identity_insert off in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework for CRUD operations. When I tried to insert data in a table which has an identity column, it throws an exception

> Identity_Insert is set to off

I don't know how to turn that on. Do I need to reconfigure entity data model for that?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the EF is including an explicit value for the PK in the INSERT. It should not do this. Make sure `StoreGeneratedPattern` is set to `identity` on the PK in the SSDL. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283139.aspx) might help.